# How to get X-RateLimit-Limit and X-Ratelimit-Remaining from Instagram gem response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I am using the [instagram-ruby-gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem). It's working great, but I'd like to be able to know if I'm ever coming up against the rate limit.

[Instagram provides this information in the form of two HTTP headers](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/instagram-api-developers/u5dvkdye-BI/Tb-Dh8zJLDkJ), but I don't know how to retrieve the headers from the API response.

A typical call I am making using the instagram gem looks like this:

```
tagged_photos = client.tag_recent_media "hashtag"
```

But if I look at the data `puts tagged_photos` I don't see any headers.

Any idea how I can access them?

Answer (score 0):

I just added ratelimit information to my fork of instagram-ruby-gem https://github.com/weyus/instagram-ruby-gem.

There's also a pull request against the actual instagram-ruby-gem, but not sure where that will go.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: The pull request was just merged in, so do a `bundle update` and you should be good!**
**Old:**

That is a known [issue](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/issues/125) and there is a [pull request](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/pull/126) for it, but it has not yet been merged. In the meantime, follow the instructions referenced in the issue:

> Change
>
> gem 'instagram'
>
> in your Gemfile to
>
> gem 'instagram', github: 'leonko/instagram-ruby-gem', branch: 'fix_utils_raw_request'